# Recipe for target ‘asterisk’ failed

Tags: ubuntu, asterisk

Ubuntu14

I am trying to configure asterisk in my PC. I have downloaded the file [asterisk-15-current.tar.gz](https://downloads.asterisk.org/pub/telephony/asterisk/asterisk-15-current.tar.gz) unzipped and started installing. Ran

./configure

and it was successful. on `Make` command, it gave the following error.

```
./libasteriskpj.so: undefined reference to ERR_reason_error_string@OPENSSL_1.0.0' ./libasteriskpj.so: undefined reference toASN1_INTEGER_get@OPENSSL_1.0.0’
./libasteriskpj.so: undefined reference to X509_NAME_oneline@OPENSSL_1.0.0'     
./libasteriskpj.so: undefined reference toERR_func_error_string@OPENSSL_1.0.0’
./libasteriskpj.so: undefined reference to SSL_CTX_ctrl@OPENSSL_1.0.0' 
./libasteriskpj.so: undefined reference toTLSv1_server_method@OPENSSL_1.0.0’
./libasteriskpj.so: undefined reference to SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb@OPENSSL_1.0.0' ./libasteriskpj.so: undefined reference toSSL_renegotiate_pending@OPENSSL_1.0.0’
./libasteriskpj.so: undefined reference to X509_STORE_set_flags@OPENSSL_1.0.0' ./libasteriskpj.so: undefined reference toEC_curve_nid2nist@OPENSSL_1.0.2’
./libasteriskpj.so: undefined reference to SSL_get_certificate@OPENSSL_1.0.0' ./libasteriskpj.so: undefined reference toSSL_get_ex_data_X509_STORE_CTX_idx@OPENSSL_1.0.0’
./libasteriskpj.so: undefined reference to SSLv3_server_method@OPENSSL_1.0.0' ./libasteriskpj.so: undefined reference toSSL_get_ex_new_index@OPENSSL_1.0.0’
./libasteriskpj.so: undefined reference to SSLv3_method@OPENSSL_1.0.0' 
./libasteriskpj.so: undefined reference toSSLv23_method@OPENSSL_1.0.0’
./libasteriskpj.so: undefined reference to BIO_new@OPENSSL_1.0.0' 
./libasteriskpj.so: undefined reference toSSL_library_init@OPENSSL_1.0.0’
./libasteriskpj.so: undefined reference to X509_get_subject_name@OPENSSL_1.0.0' ./libasteriskpj.so: undefined reference toSSL_CTX_set_cipher_list@OPENSSL_1.0.0’
./libasteriskpj.so: undefined reference to SSL_set_cipher_list@OPENSSL_1.0.0' ./libasteriskpj.so: undefined reference toX509_get_ext_d2i@OPENSSL_1.0.0’
./libasteriskpj.so: undefined reference to ERR_lib_error_string@OPENSSL_1.0.0' ./libasteriskpj.so: undefined reference tosk_value@OPENSSL_1.0.0’
./libasteriskpj.so: undefined reference to SSLv23_server_method@OPENSSL_1.0.0' ./libasteriskpj.so: undefined reference toSSL_shutdown@OPENSSL_1.0.0’
./libasteriskpj.so: undefined reference to EC_KEY_free@OPENSSL_1.0.0' 
./libasteriskpj.so: undefined reference toBIO_free@OPENSSL_1.0.0’
./libasteriskpj.so: undefined reference to `SSL_get_peer_certificate@OPENSSL_1.0.0’
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:314: recipe for target ‘asterisk’ failed
make[1]: *** [asterisk] Error 1
Makefile:386: recipe for target ‘main’ failed
make: *** [main] Error 2
```

what these errors mean and how to rectify ? or else can I ignore these errors ?

Answer (score 0):

That mean you have no openssl-dev package or have too new/too old package version(unlikly).

So likly you have install openssl-dev